# How to pass the result of a query to another page in c#.net razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

lets say i have this code ..

```
@{

if (isPost){
    cmd.CommandText="select * from tablename where id = @id and name = @name";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", Request["id"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", Request ["name"]);

            myConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            myConnection.Close();
    }
    }

<form method="post">
<input type ="text" name="id">
<input type ="text" name="name">
<input type ="submit">
</form>
```

how can i send the result of the query to another page so i can view them and let the user choose one of them ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not performing the query and the view/select on the same page?

Comment: Is this Web Pages, or MVC?

Comment: Yea because its aw page with so many field to fill then hit the search button, i cant just show the result beneath the fields and the search form, it gotta in a new page. @mason webpages

Comment: Why not send the query itself to the other page, and have the results page be responsible for retrieving the results?

Comment: @mason that could work, could u post it as answer and explain how to pass it ? i mean should i go smth like string s= cmd.CommandText(); after adding the parameters and pass the string ?

Comment: No, I would pass the search terms via the URL. I'm not sure what your ID is for, but the URL may end up looking like `mysite.com/search/Mason` if the user searched for "Mason". As for how, I've never used Web Pages so I'm not sure what the best way of doing that is.

Comment: Since the parameters are more than 15, i think passing the query text would be easier, i'll stick with it, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I would save the results as an array into a session variable.

Check this out, should be helpful [ASP Session Object](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp)

Comment: What if a user does two searches at the same time?

Comment: The second search should just overwrite the session variable data. Passing the search terms to the new page and running the query would be the preferred option.

Comment: It should overwrite, but what if it's at the same time? Users often open two tabs. Seems like they would get unexpected results in that situation, and session state is probably not the best place for storing that information unless you take care to uniquely identify it back to the request it originated from.

Comment: That definitely could happen... however in this case OP stated 15 fields to fill in before a search can be made so I think that lessens the probability. I probably would return a unique ID or key from the query running the 15 parameters and pass to the second page to run a second query from there, much less complicated.